# Invalid URL when using ChatGPT Sdk (Betalgo.OpenAI)

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm playing around with the ChatGPT sdk (Betalgo.OpenAI) in c# and using one of their samples:

```
var openAiService = new OpenAIService(new OpenAiOptions()
{
    ApiKey = "abc",
    Organization = "org-def"
});

var completionResult = await openAiService.Completions
  .CreateCompletion(new CompletionCreateRequest()
  {
    Prompt = "Once upon a time",
    MaxTokens = 20,
    Model = Models.Gpt_4
  });
```

I've change my APIKey and Organization here but they are correct in my code but I'm getting the following error:

> This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint.
> Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?

But I'm not specifying the URL so clearly this is determined by the SDK.

I've also tried it with ChatGPT 3.5 by setting the Model to `Models.Gpt_3_5_Turbo` but I'm getting the very same error.

Any ideas how to circumvent this problem?

Thanks.

**UPDATE-1**

As per @ShaharShokrani recommendation, I changed from

`var completionResult = await openAiService.Completion`

to

`var completionResult = await openAiService.ChatCompletion`

but it also meant changing the provided request. Here is the full code:

```
var openAiService = new OpenAIService(new OpenAiOptions()
{
    ApiKey = "abc",
    Organization = "org-def"
});

var completionResult = await openAiService.ChatCompletion
    .CreateCompletion(new ChatCompletionCreateRequest()
    {
       Messages = new List<ChatMessage>()
        {
            new ChatMessage("user", "Once upon a time")
        },
       MaxTokens = 20,
       Model = Models.Gpt_3_5_Turbo
    });
```

As you can see, the `CompletionCreateRequest` has been changed to `ChatCompletionCreateRequest` and `prompt` has been replaced by `Messages` which is a `List<ChatMessages>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `var completionResult = await openAiService.ChatCompletion` instead of `var completionResult = await openAiService.Completion`

Comment: The joy of out-date-documentation. I will update my sample as it has changed quite a bit and while it is not what I want to achieve, it is a starting point, so thanks for that!

Comment: Glad I could have helped. actually the doc in the github page is up to date.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had until you brought it up and I realized, I just "up" the answer! Sorry about that!

Comment: Recently I've impelemented a solution based on chat completion: https://www.octopai.com/octomize-ai/, you can take a look.